# Issue with Maven installation

Tags: java, maven

When I tried to check the version I got this message:

> Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

My environment variables for `java` and `maven` are set as such:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\
C:\Users\zz\Desktop\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `mvn` with the absolute path.

[I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04, with maven 3.6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maven/+bug/2039222) and it seems due to the mvn script not setting properly MAVEN_HOME.

The same bug may be present in windows.